# Generate NumPy array containing the indices of another NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices

I'd like to generate a `np.ndarray` NumPy array for a given shape of another NumPy array. The former array should contain the corresponding indices for each cell of the latter array.

**Example 1**

Let's say we have `a = np.ones((3,))` which has a shape of `(3,)`. I'd expect

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]]
```

since there is `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]` in `a` which can be accessed by their indices `0`, `1` and `2`.

**Example 2**

For a shape of `(3, 2)` like `b = np.ones((3, 2))` there is already very much to write. I'd expect

```
[[[0 0]
  [0 1]]

 [[1 0]
  [1 1]]

 [[2 0]
  [2 1]]]
```

since there are 6 cells in `b` which can be accessed by the corresponding indices `b[0][0]`, `b[0][1]` for the first row, `b[1][0]`, `b[1][1]` for the second row and `b[2][0]`, `b[2][1]` for the third row. Therefore we get `[0 0]`, `[0 1]`, `[1 0]`, `[1 1]`, `[2 0]` and `[2 1]` at the matching positions in the generated array.

Thank you very much for taking the time. Let me know if I can clarify the question in any way.

Comment: Your first array has shape `(3, 1)`, and the second one shape `(3, 2, 2)`. How do you go from `(3,)` to `(3, 1)` and from `(3, 2)` to `(3, 2, 2)`? Moreover, what determines the contents of the resulting arrays?

Comment: What would you expect if the inputs were, say, `(4, 1)`, or `(4, 3, 2)`?

Comment: @fuglede Thank you for your comment. I tried to clarify the question a little bit further. Regarding your question in the comment: `(3,)` results in `(3, 1)` since there are 3 cells which can be accessed by 1 index - `(3, 2)` results in `(3, 2, 2)` since there are 6 cells shaped 3 rows and 2 columns with each 2 indices to uniquely access them. So at first the generated array has the same shape as the input array - plus one additional dimension for the number of indices. `(4, 1)` would therefore result in `(4, 1, 2)` and `(4, 3, 2)` would result in `(4, 3, 2, 3)`. I hope this helps? :-)

Comment: Yep, that's clearer, thanks. In that case, it would seem that the provided answer is what you're looking for?

Comment: @fuglede Yes, I think so, too. Just wanted to clear that up in case you'd have another idea or answer. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it with `np.indices` and `np.stack`:

```
np.stack(np.indices((3,)), -1)

#array([[0],
#       [1],
#       [2]])

np.stack(np.indices((3,2)), -1)

#array([[[0, 0],
#        [0, 1]],
#       [[1, 0],
#        [1, 1]],
#       [[2, 0],
#        [2, 1]]])
```

`np.indices` returns an array of index grid where each subarray represents an axis:

```
np.indices((3, 2))

#array([[[0, 0],
#        [1, 1],
#        [2, 2]],        
#       [[0, 1],
#        [0, 1],
#        [0, 1]]])
```

Then transpose the array with `np.stack`, stacking index for each element from different axis:

```
np.stack(np.indices((3,2)), -1)

#array([[[0, 0],
#        [0, 1]],
#       [[1, 0],
#        [1, 1]],
#       [[2, 0],
#        [2, 1]]])
```